# Device Driver. Make file,External module

Tags: linux, sdk, makefile, cross-compiling, linux-toolchain

I'm trying to cross compile a helloworld kernel (2.6.x) module for ARM architecture on my intel x86 host.

The  tool chain for ARM is located at: `/home/vivek/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.07.00.00/linux-devkit/bin`

The kernel source is located at: `/home/vivek/Arago`

The `hellow.c` and `Makefile` are located on Desktop on `/home/vivek/Desktop/hellodriver`

I have given the path for cross compiler as `/home/vivek/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.07.00.00/linux-devkit/bin`

My Makefile is follows:-

```
export ARCH=arm

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-

obj-m  =Hello.o

KDIR =/home/vivek/Arago

PWD = $(shell pwd)

default:
      $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
      $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

On executing `make` I am getting

```
vivek@ubuntu:~/Desktop/hellodriver$ make

               make: Nothing to be done for `default'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the $(MAKE) lines indented with tabs or spaces? Using spaces would cause the output you said you are getting.

Comment: Which version of Make are you using? (If you're not sure, try `make -v`)

Comment: Yes They are indented well using Tab. I am using gnu make 3.2

Answer (score 0):

There is  mistake in your Makefile. As your source code name is `hellow.c`, But in your Makefile its `Hello.o`.

So change your `obj-m  =Hello.o` to `obj-m  =hellow.o`

And one more thing `Etan Reisner` said above make sure you `using Tab for command in Makefile`.